# Initialize variable w same name depending on case

Tags: java, class, variables, types, initialization

So I have this class:

```
public class x {
ConsoleIO io = new ConsoleIO();

private Board board;
private boolean playing;

public x (String een, String twee) {
    this.board = new Board();
    if (een.toUpperCase().equals("C")) {
        Computer speler1 = new Computer(een);
    } else {
        Player speler1 = new Player(een);
    }
    if (twee.toUpperCase().equals("C")) {
        this.speler2 = new Computer(twee);
    } else {
        this.speler2 = new Player(twee);
    }
    this.playing = true;
}
}
```

As you can see I want to initialize the variables speler1 & speler2 depending on the input I give.
Obviously this doesn't work. I know that I should initialize  the variables up front like this:

```
public class x {
ConsoleIO io = new ConsoleIO();

private Board board;
private boolean playing;
private Player speler1;
private Player speler2;
```

But then I'm limited to the type Player and I don't want that. Is there a way to do this properly?
*Note: Computer is an Extend of Player.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be declaring an `Object`:

```
private Object speler1;
```

Then inside your if conditions:

```
speler1 = new Computer(een);
```

or

```
speler1 = new Player(een);
```

Now, when you need to use the speler1, just use a checking like this

```
// if(speler1 instanceof Computer)
if(speler1 instanceof Player)
    player1 = (Player)speler1;
```

Comment: This won't work. Computer is a subclass of Player, so speler1 will always be instanceof Player, even if it is a Computer.

Comment: It will work. For example (`Player extends Computer`), object will match with both `Player` and `Computer`, its true. You have to check with `Player` first, and then the `Computer``.

Answer (score 0):

My answer builds on that of Sabuj:

I would try to let Computer and Player implement a common interface which defines the methods they share. You can then use that interface instead of `Object`. I otherwise see no point naming one variable the same way, if you're not going to call the same method no matter what:

```
public interface Participant {
    public void makeMove();
}
public class Player implements Participant {...}
public class Computer implements Participant {...}
```

This then allows for something like:

```
Participant p;
if (...) {
    p = new Player();
} else {
    p = new Computer();
}
...
p.makeMove();
```

You might be able to avoid some casts this way.

Comment: That sounds interesting. Could you give me an example?

Comment: I edited my answer (probably while you typed the comment), does the example explain what I mean? If not, please let me know which parts are unclear.

Comment: But i need all the methods within the objects Player and Computer. Does that mean I would have to copy all those methods. (I'm not familiar with 'interface')

Comment: An interface just tells which methods are available on any class that implements the interface (it's a rather universal OOP concept). That is why there is no implementation of the makeMove() method in the above example. Player and Computer may (and most likely will) have different implementations of this method.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is here:

```
 if (een.toUpperCase().equals("C")) {
        Computer speler1 = new Computer(een);//delete here 'Computer'
    } else {
        Player speler1 = new Player(een);//delete here 'Player'
    }
```

If `Computer` extends `Player`, why you don't declare a `speler1` as `Player` before and then initialize it depending on the case?

```
Player speler1;
...
...
...    

 if (een.toUpperCase().equals("C")) {
            speler1 = new Computer(een);
        } else {
            speler1 = new Player(een);
        }
```

Comment: Because then if I later make a temp variable in a method: Computer speler = this.speler1; "can not convert from Player to Computer".

Comment: If Computer extends Player, it means that all the fields of Computer are in Player too. If you declare a Player (more generic than Computer), you will be able to set that Player instance with a Player instance (obviously), but also with a Computer (because all of Computer fields are in Player). Maybe you can try to do a cast, something like Computer speler = (Computer) this.speler1;

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be something like that:

```
public class X {
    final ConsoleIO io = new ConsoleIO();

    private final Board board;
    private final Player player1;
    private final Player player2;
    private boolean playing;

    public X(String een, String twee) {
        this.board = new Board();

        if (een.toUpperCase().equals("C")) {
            this.player1 = new Computer();
        } else {
            this.player1 = new Human(een);
        }

        if (twee.toUpperCase().equals("C")) {
            this.player2 = new Computer();
        } else {
            this.player2 = new Human(twee);
        }

        this.playing = true;
    }
}
```

*Note:*

Both, `Human` and `Computer` are subclasses of `Player`. Move common methods/fields into the `Player` base class. If you do it right, it might not be necessary to distinguish between `Computer` and `Human` later on.

For example, there might be an abstract method `move` in the `Player` base class that is implemented individually in subclasses: `Computer#move` uses an algorithm to calculate the next move; `Human#move` asks the human player to input the next move. So if it's turn of `player1`, you simply call `player1.move()`, regardless of if it's a `Human` or `Computer`.

Comment: I tried that, but then the variables are still recognized as Player types

Comment: Don't understand what you mean. Sure, they are Player objects. Computer extends Player, Human extends Player.

Comment: Nope, if I later make a temp variable in a method: Computer speler = this.speler1; "can not convert from Player to Computer".

Comment: Why do you want to do this? This should not be necessary if you think/design object oriented. See my notes above. In rare cases you can still determine if it's a computer or human by using instanceof.